# rust statrs sample not in scope?

Tags: rust

I can't figure out why I get an error on this code:

```
extern crate rand;
extern crate statrs;

use rand::distributions::Distribution;
use statrs::distribution::Beta;

fn main() {
    let beta = Beta::new(1.0, 2.0).unwrap();
    beta.sample(&mut rand::thread_rng());
}
```

The error message I get is:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `sample` found for type `statrs::distribution::Beta` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:9:10
  |
9 |     beta.sample(&mut rand::thread_rng());
  |          ^^^^^^
  |
  = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
help: the following trait is implemented but not in scope, perhaps add a `use` for it:
  |
4 | use rand::distributions::Distribution;
  |
```

I've added the exact use that it suggests, but the error stays. I've now for the better part of an hour tried taking everything I can think of in scope, out of scope, writing the `use` statements this way and that and I can't figure it out.

I checked both the source and the documentation of statrs and the `sample()` function implemented in the `Distribution` trait.

What do I need to change so I can sample random values from the `Beta` function?

Comment: `statrs v0.10.0` requires `rand v0.5.6` but you are using `rand v0.6.5`. Unify the versions.

Comment: @Shepmaster - turns out to solve the problem. Thanks. Didn't think about that.